# Intellij Repository Diff Read only

Tags: intellij-idea, repository

I am using Intellij on Macbook pro for development and I would like to know how can I open a file for Edit in "Repository Diff" mode.

It opens a file in "Read-Only" mode and then to compare and make the change, I need to manually open each file.

It would be nice to be able to make the changes in the pane where it shows the difference in a diff.

Something similar to Meld's compare and edit-in-place.

Thanks!

Comment: Right-click on the file in git tool window -> Edit source

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov - thanks. Although this was not the exact answer, I did find what I was looking for!